# Isogenous Elliptic Curves and Reduction Type

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am looking for a full proof (or a reference containing a detailed proof) of the following fact:

Why do $\mathbb Q$-isogenous elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$ have the same primes of a) split multiplicative reduction b) nonsplit multiplicative reduction, and c) additive reduction? I need this to be true to conclude that their $L$-functions match. The answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148559/isogeny-classes-and-reduction-types-of-elliptic-curves-at-primes-of-bad-reductio) provided no details, which are what I am after.

Comment: One way is to prove that they have the same L-functions, e.g. because they have isomorphic Tate modules (then for good places, the famous $1 - a_p X + pX^2$ is the char. poly. of $Frob_p$ on $T_\ell E$; this is in Silverman's book). For bad places, see e.g., p.218-219 of "Elliptic_Curves,_Hilbert_Modular_Forms_and_Galois_Deformations" (i.e., Dokchitser's "Notes on the Parity Conjecture"). A more direct way is described in the answer you link. Did you try to follow this answer? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The direct answer is a little scant and not general; I like details. I also am using this to show the L-functions are equal.

Comment: 1) You can try to prove that the L-functions are equal via the Tate modules. In Silverman's AEC book, Corollary VII.7.2 states that isogenous elliptic curves have the same primes of good reduction, as a consequence of Néron-Ogg-Shafarevitch criterion (see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126926/). 2) As for the more direct appraoch, if you like details (which is good), then you can try to fill them up yourself; what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local factor of the $L$-function is defined as it is because of the Tate module: it is defined to be
$$\det(1-p^{-s}\mathrm{Frob}_p | V_\ell^{I_p})^{-1},$$
where $V_\ell(E)^{I_p}$ is the subspace of the Galois representation $V_\ell(E)$ on which the inertia group $I_p$ acts trivially (so it's the whole of $V_\ell(E)$ if $E$ has good reduction at $p$), viewed as a representation of $G_{\mathbb Q_p}/I_p\cong G_{\mathbb F_p}$.

This definition explains the slightly more ad hoc definition usually given for primes of bad reduction! It has the advantage of being completely uniform.

Since $V_\ell(E)^{I_p}\cong V_\ell(E')^{I_p}$ is isogeny invariant, so is the local factor.

Comment: Nice answer. In the last line, I don't see how one would use Tate's theorem to have that $V_\ell(E)$ is an isogeny invariant (I can see howver that Faltings theorem says something about the converse: if the $V_\ell$ are isomorphic as Galois representations, then the elliptic curves over $\Bbb Q$ are isogenous).

Comment: Where can I see a discussion of why L-functions are defined this way and how this gives the various well-known formulas for the local L-functions for each reduction type?

Comment: @Watson you're right, it's nothing to do with Tate. It's just the fact that isogenous elliptic curves have isomorphic Galois reps.

Comment: @JohnnyApple It's carefully worked out in Remark 3.6 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5389.pdf)